# How to find range of function with restricted domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

**Background:** I was trying to solving this question:

> Find $\frac{1}{x}$, if $x \in(-1,3)-\{0\}$.
>
> I know that I can solve the question by drawing the graph of the function, $\frac{1}{x}$, then I should find the values of the function at $-1$ and $3$, then I should "look" for the values the function assumes between the two values.
> But this method is impractical; what if the function is not easily "graphable"? How should one proceed then?
> That's why I tried to find algebraic method to solve this question and hence this type of questions.

I tried to solve it, algebraically,  like this:

> I know that domain of a inverse function is equal to the range of the function. So to find the range of $f(x)\frac{1}{x}$, with the restriction, I should first find the inverse of the function.
>
> The inverse ***of*** *the* function is $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, with $x, f^{-1}(x)\not= 0 $ and  $f^{-1}(x) \in(-1,3)$.

Now all I have to do is to find Domain of this new function. But I don't know how to proceed from here. *And this method is also impractical, because not every function is one  to one function.*

**Question:** The question is how to find range of a function with restricted domain, algebraically? *Note* that I am not asking how to solve that particular question of finding $\frac{1}{x}…$, but what I am asking is methods to solve this type of questions, algebraically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem that requires that you stretch your intuition.

Let $f(x) = (1/x).$

Then, $f(-1) = (-1).$

Further, as $x$ goes from $(-1)$ towards $0$ [i.e. approaches $0$ **from below**], $f(x)$ goes to $-\infty.$

Similarly, $f(3) = (1/3)$

and as $x$ goes from $(3)$ towards $0$, $f(x)$ goes to $+\infty.$

So, the range of the function, in the domain $\{x: -1 < x < 3, x \neq 0\}$, is

$(-\infty, -1) \bigcup (1/3, \infty)$.

That is, the range is $\{x < -1\} \bigcup \{1/3 < x\}.$

This should help you graph the function.

Comment: In this particular cases the answer was easy to find, but what if the question was something like: find $\frac{\sqrt{3x-5}+2}{x^{3}+22 }$, if $x \in (9,28)$? I don't have single clue about what the graph would look like; how the graph will behave between the points, how then shall I solve this question (without using graphing tools)?

Comment: But you may use calculator, though.

Comment: @HitlerDean In your comment/question, the first thing to notice is that for $x \in (9, 28)$, the denominator ranges from $751$ to $21974$, and thus the denominator is always positive.The next things to notice are [1] the numerator will (also) always be positive, throughout that range, and [2] the numerator increases much more slowly   than the denominator.  **Again**, your primary weapon is your **intuition**.  Clearly, the function will therefore be strictly decreasing, so the obvious thing to do is to eval the function at (for example) $x=9$, $x=18,$ and $x=28$, and then rough out the graph.

Comment: This is last question. How will you find the value of $\sqrt{x^2-4}$? Thanks.

Comment: @Διαισθητικός I am unsure what you are asking here.  I interpret your question to be if $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 4}$, then what is the domain of $f(x)$.  Please advise if I have misinterpreted your question.  Anyway, since negative square roots are disallowed, you have to identify all $x$ such that $x^2 - 4 \geq 0.$  For $0 \leq x$, this is clearly the subset $\{x ~: ~2 \leq x\}.$  Since $x^2$ is an even function, you also have the subset $\{x ~: ~x \leq -2\}.$  Therefore the domain is $(-\infty, -2] \cup [2, + \infty).$

Comment: Thanks for your fast comment, I don't know how to thank you for your help. In the question I am asking what will be range of the given function.

Comment: @Διαισθητικός If $x=2, f(x) = 0.$  As $x \to \infty, f(x)$ increases without bound.  So, for $(x)$ restricted by $x \geq 2$, the range is $[0, + \infty).$  With $x^2$ an even function, so is $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 - 4}.$  Therefore, in the domain of $(-\infty, -2] \cup [2, +\infty),$ the range is $[0, +\infty).$

Comment: Thanks, you're very smart man; all of your answers are correct. By the way do you have any recommendations on book on High School maths. More specifically book*s* on Algebra like inequality, logarithm, trigonometry, sequence and series, Complex analysis, Matrices and determinant.

Comment: @Διαισθητικός No, sorry, no recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly algebraically but you might find it useful.

You can look at the behaviour of the function, for example, for a continuous function, look at its maximum and minimum. And a particular case of the above, if the function is increasing (or decreasing) simply evaluate it at the extremes of the domain. (In both cases I assume the domain is an interval, but you can generalise for example to a union of several intervals or a function defined by parts).

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Illustration(s) will be usefull. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: You seem to be new on Stack Exchange, please have a look on this [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) post.